# What do you call a "mock interview" with your own self?

Tags: word-request

Is it just a mock interview? Usually, a mock interview is done with 2 persons at least, but what if you do a mock interview with yourself? Is there a word for it? I am thinking there's no word for it, but maybe there's a way to say this in an eloquent way of which I am not aware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Rehearsal interview, fake interview, interview prep, interview role play.**